# JS slider not appearing upon first load in IE, only on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, refresh

There is a JS slider section on [proheatinc.com](http://www.proheatinc.com/) that does not appear upon first load in Internet Explorer. Once refreshed, it pops up and works just fine.

Any ideas as to how I can fix this would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Could you poste some code examples from this website where the slider is created?

Comment: FYI, same issue in Chrome by me.

Comment: Try moving the `<script>` of the slider _BEFORE_ the HTML code of the slider. (In the `<header>`, or at the begging of the `<body>`). I didn't have much time reviewing all the code on the site, but on the first glance, this seems the be your issue.